# DraftJs creating simplest possible custom block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

what would be the easiest way to implement custom block in Draft?
At the moment I'm using this function for default blocks

```
  editorToggleBlockType = (blockType) => {
    this.onChange(
      RichUtils.toggleBlockType(
        this.state.editorState,
        blockType
      )
    );
  }
```

then I can apply custom class using blockStyler

```
  blockStyler = (block) => {
    if (block.getType() === 'unstyled') {
     return 'paragraph';
    } else {
     return `custom-${block.getType()}`;
    }
  }
```

Sadly blockType accepts only default types like blockquote, ol, code-block etc. and on custom type gives me an error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'wrapper' of undefined
```

My question is - how to force editor to accept custom block types so I can apply className to them? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You need to define it in `blockRenderMap`.

From the [docs](https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-custom-block-render-map.html#content):

```
const blockRenderMap = Immutable.Map({
  'atomic': {
    // the docs use 'MyCustomBlock', but I changed it to 'atomic' to make it easier to follow.
    // element is used during paste or html conversion to auto match your component;
    // it is also retained as part of this.props.children and not stripped out
    element: 'section',
    wrapper: <MyCustomBlock {...this.props} />
  }
});


// Include 'paragraph' as a valid block and updated the unstyled element but
// keep support for other draft default block types
const extendedBlockRenderMap = Draft.DefaultDraftBlockRenderMap.merge(blockRenderMap);

class RichEditor extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Editor
        ...
        blockRenderMap={extendedBlockRenderMap}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Rather confusingly, all this does is wrap your custom block in whatever is specified in the `wrapper` key. The actual block is then rendered by `blockRendererFn`, as in the [docs](https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-block-components.html#content):

```
function myBlockRenderer(contentBlock) {
  const type = contentBlock.getType();
  if (type === 'atomic') {
    return {
      component: MediaComponent,
      editable: false,
      props: {
        foo: 'bar',
      },
    };
  }
}

// Then...
import {Editor} from 'draft-js';
class EditorWithMedia extends React.Component {
  ...
  render() {
    return <Editor ... blockRendererFn={myBlockRenderer} />;
  }
}
```

If we follow this example verbatim, you'd get a block that looked something like:

```
...
<MyCustomBlock>
  <MediaComponent />
</MyCustomBlock>
...
```

And your `className` from `blockStyleFn` would get passed to `MyCustomBlock`, so you can pass it down to whichever native DOM node you like. That's also why you were getting the `TypeError` -- DraftJS couldn't find your custom block in `blockRenderMap`!

I hope this answers your question. DraftJS can be confusing, but it's a very powerful framework for building RTEs.

Comment: That helped a lot, thanks.
I implemented sth like that:
`const blockRenderMap = Immutable.Map({
      'backgroundColor': {
        element: 'section',
        wrapper: <div>{this.props.children}</div>
      }
    });`

And than blockStyler applies correct class to set backgroundColor.
Sadly it works only on regular text, italic or bold, when I wont to change Background color on H1,h2,h3 elements or lists, it removes previous styling. How can I make it to wrap selected elements instead of replacing them?

Comment: In that case you should use blockRendererFn to render a custom H1 etc. You can pass the block components any arbitrary props you like, allowing you to use i one styles for 100% freedom. Using wrapper in blockRenderMap is a lot less flexible. It's use case is targeted more at wrapping blocks with HOCs to implement things like drag and drop.

Comment: So instead of if (block.getType() === 'atomic'), you can check for 'header-one' etc etc or really whatever custom block you can think of.

Comment: Isn't there easier method to achieve something like this simplistic example:
`<div class="backgroundColor-change"><h1>Heading1</h1><h2>Heading2</h2><div>`
What am I trying to achieve is to have functionality that wrap selected elements in parent block and apply background-color on it.

Comment: You can change the class based on block data, but you're better off with a custom block component imo.

Comment: Also you can't have multiple headers in one block if you don't use a custom block component. You can't wrap multiple blocks in this way. One wrapper for one block.

Comment: Well, that is complicating things a bit. I'll keep on trying.
Alright, thanks for the fulfilling answers.